# How to get access token for Azure DevOps from Microsoft Teams app?

Tags: angular, azure, microsoft-teams

I have created an angular app and integrated with  MS Teams using tab.

I'm also able to authenticate user within microsoft teams app and able to get logged in user token using Microsoft Teams Javascript SDK.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/overview/msteams-client?view=msteams-client-js-latest#using-the-sdk

I'm not getting how to authenticate Azure DevOps within MS Teams app.

How to get access token for Azure DevOps within my custom  teams angular app, so that I can use it to deal with Azure DevOps?

Comment: Is the application created in Azure AD?

Comment: If the posted answer resolves your question, please mark it as the answer by clicking the check mark. Doing so helps others find answers to their questions. See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your application is in Azure AD, it is very simple to obtain an access token for Azure DevOps, you only need to set the scope to: `https://app.vssps.visualstudio.com/user_impersonation`.

First, you need to grant the **Azure DevOps** `user_impersonation` **delegation permission** to the application, and then use the auth code flow to obtain an access token.

[image]

[image]

Next, use the [auth code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow) to obtain an access token.

1. Request an authorization code in the browser.

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant id}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id={client id}
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri={redirect_uri}
&response_mode=query
&scope=https://app.vssps.visualstudio.com/user_impersonation
&state=12345
```

2.Redeem token.

[image]

Parse the token and view the `aud` claim.

[image]

The token will contain the logged-in user information,  and have full access to Visual Studio Team Services REST APIs.

[sample](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-auth-samples).

Comment: This was very close for me, but to get the token to have access to the Azure DevOps REST APIs, I had to change my scope from "https://app.vssps.visualstudio.com/user_impersonation" to "499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798/.default".  Then everything worked perfectly.

Comment: Using the cli: `az account get-access-token --resource 499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798 --scope 499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798/.default --output tsv | cut -f1`